# Skip the installation of Compass during the unattended installation of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, chocolatey

I use a `chocolatey` package to install `MongoDB` in unattended mode and the installer try to install also `Compass`. The installation of `Compass` is done by downloading the msi, but the link is broken and the download fails. The consequence is that the whole package won't be installed. I checked the documentation of `MongoDB` but I couldn't find anything about arguments to skip the installation of `Compass`. Does somebody know if there is an undocumented argument to skip it?

```
MSI (s) (5C:C0) [11:33:29:831]: Executing op: CacheSizeFlush(,)
MSI (s) (5C:C0) [11:33:29:831]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=InstallCompassScript,Description=Installing MongoDB Compass... (this may take a few minutes),)
MSI (s) (5C:C0) [11:33:29:847]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=InstallCompassScript,ActionType=1025,Source=BinaryData,Target=WixQuietExec64,CustomActionData="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\InstallCompass.ps1' ; exit $($Error.Count)")
MSI (s) (5C:80) [11:33:29:847]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIF4B0.tmp, Entrypoint: WixQuietExec64
MSI (s) (5C:EC) [11:33:29:847]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (5C:EC) [11:33:29:847]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 2952 (0xB88).
MSI (s) (5C:50) [11:33:29:878]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (5C:50) [11:33:29:878]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Impersonated custom action server.
WixQuietExec64:  Downloading Compass from https://compass.mongodb.com/api/v2/download/latest/compass-community/stable/windows
WixQuietExec64:  Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
WixQuietExec64:  At C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\InstallCompass.ps1:35 char:1
WixQuietExec64:  + Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $CompassUrl -OutFile $CompassExe
WixQuietExec64:  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
WixQuietExec64:      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) , WebExc
WixQuietExec64:     eption
WixQuietExec64:      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
WixQuietExec64:  
WixQuietExec64:  Error 0x80070001: Command line returned an error.
WixQuietExec64:  Error 0x80070001: QuietExec64 Failed
WixQuietExec64:  Error 0x80070001: Failed in ExecCommon method
CustomAction InstallCompassScript returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
MSI (s) (5C:C0) [11:33:30:847]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035
MSI (s) (5C:C0) [11:33:30:847]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (5C:C0) [11:33:30:847]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
Action ended 11:33:30: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
```

Comment: Can you clarify what packages you are using?  Are they hosted on chocolatey.org?  I see a MongoDB package, but I don't see a Compass one.  Perhaps you can mention exactly what commands you are running.

Answer (score 2):

If you downaload the msi file and run the next command it should work:

```
msiexec.exe  /qn /i mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.6.*-signed.msi SHOULD_INSTALL_COMPASS=0

msiexec.exe 
    /qn 
    /i mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.6.*-signed.msi
    SHOULD_INSTALL_COMPASS=0
```

where * is the revisión of the 3.6 version that you want/need to install

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with 3.6.0, but 3.4.7 installs ok.

Maybe when the 4.x chocolatey package is available, it will work nicely.

Answer (score -1):

Has anyone resolved this issue?

The command I run is choco install MongoDB --version 3.6.0.

If I run the installer manually with compass checked, it also fails. If I uncheck compass, I have no issues.

Is there a command we can add that will force choco to ignore compass?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please do not post questions as answers.

Comment: Its a bit difficult to post a comment when you must have a 50 reputation to do so...